# Can I use CSS variables to add custom Adobe fonts to a website?

Tags: css, fonts, var

I need to import a font family from Adobe to a wordpress site using a theme (BeTheme), and I'd like to streamline how the font's are applied across the site as much as I can. I was trying to utilize var() to do this but it doesn't seem to be working.

I had tried something like this:

```
:root {
    --futura-pt-bold: "futura-pt-bold", sans-serif !important;
    --futura-pt: "futura-pt", sans-serif !important;
    
    --ft-wt-3: 300;
    --ft-wt-4: 400;
    --ft-wt-7: 700;
    
    --fut-bld: var(--futura-pt-bold) var(--ft-wt-7);
}

p {
    font: var(--fut-bld);
}
```

The result would be applying the font Futura PT Bold using only var(--fut-bld) but it's not working. What am I missing here, or is this just not possible?

Comment: It's possible if the person already has that font installed on their computer. Otherwise you need to provide links to the font files so they can be used in CSS

Comment: I have them linked properly in the head of the site

Comment: Well please include that in your question since that code is relevant. I have no way of knowing that if you don't show that code.  Your code example should be easily reproduced where no one has to take guesses at what you may or may not have done.

Comment: You just can't concatenate CSS variables.  Use separated font properties like `font-family: var(--fut-bld); font-weight: var(--ft-wt-7);`